# How to avoid having duplicated code between animated (completionBlock) and non-animated code

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, animation, duplicates

I have a question I have asked myself many time. Let's look at the example below :

```
 if (animated) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{            
        view.frame = newFrame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        // same code as below
        SEL selector = @selector(sidePanelWillStartMoving:);
        if ([currentPanningVC conformsToProtocol:@protocol(CHSurroundedViewDelegate)] &&
            [currentPanningVC respondsToSelector:selector]) {
            [(id)self.currentPanningVC sidePanelWillStartMoving:self.currentPanningVC];
        }

        if ([centerVC conformsToProtocol:@protocol(CHSurroundedViewDelegate)] &&
            [centerVC respondsToSelector:selector]) {
            [(id)centerVC sidePanelWillStartMoving:self.currentPanningVC];
        }
    }];
}
else {
    view.frame = newFrame;

    // same code as before
    SEL selector = @selector(sidePanelWillStartMoving:);
    if ([currentPanningVC conformsToProtocol:@protocol(CHSurroundedViewDelegate)] &&
        [currentPanningVC respondsToSelector:selector]) {
        [(id)self.currentPanningVC sidePanelWillStartMoving:self.currentPanningVC];
    }

    if ([centerVC conformsToProtocol:@protocol(CHSurroundedViewDelegate)] &&
        [centerVC respondsToSelector:selector]) {
        [(id)centerVC sidePanelWillStartMoving:self.currentPanningVC];
    }
}
```

The code in the completion block and the non-animated code block is the same. And this is often like this, I means the results of both are the same, except, one was animated.

This really bothers me to have two blocks of code that are exactly the same, how can I avoid that please ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create block object and use it both places!.

```
void (^yourBlock)(BOOL finished);

yourBlock = ^{

        // same code as below
        SEL selector = @selector(sidePanelWillStartMoving:);
        if ([currentPanningVC conformsToProtocol:@protocol(CHSurroundedViewDelegate)] &&
            [currentPanningVC respondsToSelector:selector]) {
            [(id)self.currentPanningVC sidePanelWillStartMoving:self.currentPanningVC];
        }

        if ([centerVC conformsToProtocol:@protocol(CHSurroundedViewDelegate)] &&
            [centerVC respondsToSelector:selector]) {
            [(id)centerVC sidePanelWillStartMoving:self.currentPanningVC];
        }
    }
```

In your code,

```
    if (animated) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{            
        view.frame = newFrame;
    } completion:yourBlock];
}
else {
yourBlock();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Create block variables for your animation and completion code, and invoke them yourself in the non-animated case. For example:

```
void (^animatableCode)(void) = ^{
    view.frame = newFrame;
};

void (^completionBlock)(BOOL finished) = ^{
    // ...
};

if (animated) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:animatableCode completion:completionBlock];

} else {
    animatableCode();
    completionBlock(YES);
}
```